# Angular JS: attribute not influenced by $scope...?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

Angular newbie here.
I have the following div:

```
<div id="mainfr" data-curpos="dy[ {{curPosObj.dy}} ]" ...>blah blah </div>
```

And in my controller I have:

```
var nxtest = angular.module('nxtest', []);
var appController = nxtest.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.curPosObj = { dir: "down", dy:5 };
    $scope.clr = window.setTimeout(function(){ $scope.curPosObj.dy = 777;
window.clearTimeout($scope.clr); }, 5000); //see if the attr responds to a random change
}])
```

In firebug, inspecting the scope object shows that it is indeed modified. I want to understand why the bound attribute {{curPosObj.dy}} is not 'bound' and the view does not respond to the changing values? Thanks very much in advance.

**Update**: added link to plunker as suggested - the red text never changes:
http://plnkr.co/edit/HJxEpgR8VepxuT47zJDJ?p=preview

**Update 2**: OK so there may be a separate issue here - the red text is in a pseudo element whose contrent attribute depends on the main divs attribute... and I'm not calling setAttribute anywhere... but regardless: in firebug, the 'data-curpos' attribute itself is NOT updating, never mind the pseudo elem that depends on it...

Comment: What is curpos?  Is that an Angular directive?  Can you provide a runnable sample / Plunker?

Comment: it's just a random object I made up, with random values just to check data binding. I'm going to try plunkering it (never tried before)...

Answer (score 1):

That's because angular doesn't tracking scope changes out of the dygest cycle and `window.setTimeout` that case. You should use the `$timeout` service instead of `window.setTimeout` or put code which chenge scope into `$scope.$apply` call

[angularjs API reference - $timeout service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

[angularjs API reference - scope guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

try this:

```
var nxtest = angular.module('nxtest', []);
var appController = nxtest.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout',
  function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.curPosObj = {
      dir: "down",
      dy: 5
    };
    $scope.clrPromise  = $timeout(function() {
      $scope.curPosObj.dy = 777;
    }, 5000); //see if the attr responds to a random change
```

}
])

Comment: I can't get it to work for me :-( I'm going to read a bit more through the service and scope guides. Note: initially, I wasn't using timeouts... I had a directive that had a two-way binding with scope.curPosObj, and it was successfully modifying the scope (I checked the parent scope obj in firebug)... It just wasn't trickling through the bound attribute, so i nuked the directive and just randomly changed the values with a timeout. Eitherway, the attribute didn't update. Have to step out for a few hours, but will be back once I read through the API refs you mention. thanks!

Comment: Whar is the `by`? Is it some array defined in scope? If so, you need to interpolate whole expression: `data-curpos="{{dy[curPosObj.dy]}}"`